# "bower install" failing on jenkins, but runs well through command line

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bower, bower-install

### I'm getting error "Permission denied (publickey)." when I'm doing shell command in jenkins:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
echo $PATH

npm install
bower cache clean
bower install
```

---

I'm connecting through SSH to private git repo in STASH.
My code is failing on **random** custom dependencies in "bower install".
I did all jenkins-stash ssh configuration like https://wiki.csiro.au/display/ASC/Connecting+Jenkins+to+Stash

### Here is exact error what I'm getting:

```
.
bower bootstrap#~3.3.4                                                  extract  archive.tar.gz
bower bootstrap#~3.3.4                                              resolved git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.5
bower backbone#~1.2.0                                                extract archive.tar.gz
bower backbone#~1.2.0                                               resolved git://github.com/jashkenas/backbone.git#1.2.3
bower custom-theme#*                                     ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@stash.companyName:7999/cpui/custom-theme.git", exit code of #128 Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Additional error details:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! another-custom-theme@0.1.56 postinstall: `bower cache clean && bower install && grunt copy:hooks`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the another-custom-theme@0.1.56 postinstall script 'bower cache clean && bower install && grunt copy:hooks'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the another-custom-theme package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower cache clean && bower install && grunt copy:hooks
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls another-custom-theme
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/CUSTOM_TEST/workspace/npm-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

The only notice, that everything is OK if I'm running all that commands from command line directly.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run the GIT command (that one that fails) from command line using the private key used in Jenkins?

Comment: it runs successfully. adding all dev dependencies to right folders.

Comment: Does Jenkins use the same ssh version as you when you run from cli? And can you access the log on the stash.companyName and see if the error is more descriptive?

Comment: Yes, I've added jenkins user with my private key. If key is not valid - on Git source you can see something like that ->                                                `Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://git@stash.companyName:7999/projectName.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: We have ssh configureren which works (like this) so it is weird this doesn't work. Have you tried to put the key on disk I.e. In ~/.ssh and see if that works?